# using d3.forceSimulatio with d3.hierarchy in version7

Tags: d3.js

I'm trying to use d3.hierarchy.

I'm following this example:
https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-tree?collection=@d3/d3-force

I'm using d3 v7.

I'm getting this typing error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(nodesData?: SimulationNodeDatum[]): Simulation<SimulationNodeDatum, undefined>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ name: string; children: { name: string; children: ({ name: string; children: ({ name: string; value: number; children?: undefined; } | { name: string; children: { name: string; value: number; }[]; value?: undefined; })[]; value?: undefined; } | { ...; })[]; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SimulationNodeDatum[]'.
      Type '{ name: string; children: { name: string; children: ({ name: string; children: ({ name: string; value: number; children?: undefined; } | { name: string; children: { name: string; value: number; }[]; value?: undefined; })[]; value?: undefined; } | { ...; })[]; }[]; }' has no properties in common with type 'SimulationNodeDatum'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(nodesData?: SimulationNodeDatum[]): Simulation<SimulationNodeDatum, SimulationLinkDatum<SimulationNodeDatum>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ name: string; children: { name: string; children: ({ name: string; children: ({ name: string; value: number; children?: undefined; } | { name: string; children: { name: string; value: number; }[]; value?: undefined; })[]; value?: undefined; } | { ...; })[]; }[]; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SimulationNodeDatum[]'.ts(2769)
const nodes: {
    name: string;
    children: {
        name: string;
        children: ({
            name: string;
            children: ({
                name: string;
                value: number;
                children?: undefined;
            } | {
                name: string;
                children: {
                    name: string;
                    value: number;
                }[];
                value?: undefined;
            })[];
            value?: undefined;
        } | {
            ...;
        })[];
    }[];
}[]
```

Also on links:

```
Types of property 'source' are incompatible.
      Type 'HierarchyNode<{ name: string; children: { name: string; children: ({ name: string; children: ({ name: string; value: number; children?: undefined; } | { name: string; children: { name: string; value: number; }[]; value?: undefined; })[]; value?: undefined; } | { ...; })[]; }[]; }>' is not assignable to type 'string | number | SimulationNodeDatum'
```